# In db data is not inserting from django

Tags: python, django

In an django app i am getting user submitted form data which am trying to insert into mysql db but even though the request.keys matches with db column name values are not inserted in db

```
if request:
    user=User()
    for k,v in request.POST.items():
        if str(k)!="csrfmiddlewaretoken":
            if(k=='name'):
                user.name=v     #like this data will be saved

             user.save()



if request:
    user=User()
    for k,v in request.POST.items():
        if str(k)!="csrfmiddlewaretoken":
                user.k=v     #like this data will not be saved

             user.save()
```

Actually i used same db column name and html form tag name so request.POST.keys() matches with db column name , but if i hardcode column it is working but directly if i iterate from request.post.keys and save its not working

Comment: I think you haven't called User object at all.
Try this : user = User.objects.all() instead user=User()

Comment: @Romans8.38-39 User.objects.all() return if any data/object stored in user model.. Actually my problem is even post.keys matches with db col name its not saving

Comment: Your code is very unsecure. Don't do that. Use Django forms of modelforms to validate user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not work because `user.k` implies you are trying to assign the value `v` to the attribute `k` of the `User` instance, which does not exist.

You can use [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) for this purpose if you are bent on doing it this way.

```
for k,v in request.POST.items():
    if str(k)!="csrfmiddlewaretoken":
        setattr(user, k, v)
    user.save()
```

Comment: ya thanks its worked but still am not getting whats the difference if you see in django tutorial part1 they assigned polls.id=1 same way i am setting user attributes... User object by default will have all the column as attributes right

Comment: `k` in your case is a variable, thats the reason it is not working. In your case, it is assuming `k`  is a column (model attribute) - just like `id` in the tutorial example. Example, if `k` is `first_name`, you are assuming `user.k` evaluates to `user.first_name` , but it does not.

Comment: if k='firstname' then user.k ='dar' will not set but user.firstname='dar' will set,so  user.k!= user.firstname , then what exactly is user.k will be

Comment: It saves it in attribute `k`- to test, do this - before `user.save`, just do `print user.k` - It will give you some valid value, however, when you try to `save`, it looks for `k` in models.py's `class User` and sees if `k` is a column - if not, it just discards it.

Comment: ya thanks i got it... is their any other way to store data in db

Comment: you mean any way other than _save()_ ?